# Cannot resolve a project in .NET Core 1.1 using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a VS 2015 (Ver 14 Update 3, latest .NET Core tooling installed) solution which contains several class libraries and a executable project. I am using ASP.NET Core 1.1. The problem is that despite right clicking on the "Resources" of the client program and ensuring that the library project is checked/included, and despite the library project being listed as a dependency in the Project.json file (and restored of course), VS is still telling me that it cannot resolve the namespace/classes from the class library project. Sometimes it even builds, other times it won't, but my code is littered with red and when I hit alt+enter, ReSharper gives me the option to add usings and references, and when it does this, everything is still red and cannot be located.

Is there anything aside from the Resources, project.json, and using statements that I need to handle in ASP.NET Core to include a class library properly? Thanks.

PS: I also tried importing the DLL assembly but it said I could only import .NET Framework assemblies in the project, so that failed as well. Also, ***my colleague is not having this problem on his machine with the same tooling.***

**Project.json**:

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "Churnite.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Churnite.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      }
    }
    },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  }
}
```

Note: Churnite.Data is the project that is not working. the "Data" portion is what VS is saying that it cannot locate.

Comment: Churnite.Data restored and build successfully ?

Comment: Yes, I even removed it and re-added and watched it restore a couple of times. That's what's baffling my mind! For example in my controller I have: `using Churnite.Data.Abstraction;
using Churnite.Domain.Entities;` at the top and Data and Domain are both red and giving me "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: change your project.json in all projects
`"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",` to  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1",
      "type": "platform"
    }
and `"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {`
to
`"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {`

Answer (score 0):

your should update the references in your `project.json` file for `netcoreapp1.0` or `Microsoft.NetCore.App` version 1.0 to version 1.1

[image]
 [update an existing project to ASP.NET Core 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/)

Comment: Unfortunately I have done these changes successfully, but it does not solve the original problem. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: Run `dotnet restore` command on `cmd` in each project directory which `project.jso`n wile reside. Let me know what error you get ?

Answer (score 0):

You could be done some changes in project.json:

1. Microsoft.NETCore.App to

   "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
         "version": "1.1.0",
         "type": "platform"
       }
2. frameworks to

   "frameworks": {
       "netcoreapp1.1": {
         "imports": [
           "dotnet5.6",
           "portable-net45+win8"
         ]
       }
     }

Hope this help!

Comment: Unfortunately I have done these changes successfully, but it does not solve the original problem. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

In .Net Core 1.1 *project.json* has been retired in favour of an MSBuild compatible csproj file. So you can edit the .csproj file to use .Net 4.6 (or other version)

Instead of:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Set:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Now you can reference a project, like a library in .Net 4.6

Hope this helps.